# Duplicated custom object in NSSet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hash, nsset

I have some problems about the NSMutableSet in Objective-C.
I learnt that the NSSet will compare the two objects' hash code to decide whether they are identical or not.
The problems is, I implemented a class that is subclass of `NSObject` myself. There is a property `NSString *name` in that class. What I want to do is when instances of this custom class has the same variable value of "name" , they should be identical, and such identical class should not be duplicated when adding to an NSMutableSet.

So I override the `- (NSUInteger)hash` function, and the debug shows it returns the same hash for my two instances `obj1, obj2 (obj1.name == obj2.name)`. But when I added obj1, obj2 to an `NSMutableSet`, the `NSMutableSet` still contained both obj1, obj2 in it.

I tried two `NSString` which has the same value, then added them to `NSMutableSet`, the set will only be one `NSString` there.

What could be the solution? Thank you for any help!

The custom Class:
Object.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Object : NSObject

@property (retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

Object.m

```
@implementation Object
@synthesize name;

-(BOOL)isEqualTo:(id)obj {
    return [self.name isEqualToString:[(Object *)obj name]] ? true : false;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
    return [[self name] hash];

}
@end
```

and main:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Object.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Object *obj1 = [[Object alloc]init];
        Object *obj2 = [[Object alloc]init];
        obj1.name = @"test";
        obj2.name = @"test";
        NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil];
        NSLog(@"%d", [obj1 isEqualTo:obj2]);
        NSLog(@"%ld", [set count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you also override `isEqual:`?

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `hash`, `isEqual` and how you add the objects to the set?

Comment: You implemented the wrong method. `isEqual:` is not the same as `isEqualTo:` You also can't assume that the object you're testing for equality even _has_ a property called `name`. You should have a read of [Mike Ash's post about equality and hashing](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of implementing `isEqualTo:` you have to implement `isEqual:`

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    return [object isKindOfClass:[MyObject class]] &&
           [self.name isEqual:[(MyObject *)object name]];
}
```

This will (probably falsely) return `NO` if both `self.name` and `object.name` are `nil`. If you want to return `YES` if both properties are `nil` you should use

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[MyObject class]]) {
        return (!self.name && ![(MyObject *)object name]) ||
        [self.name isEqual:[(MyObject *)object name]];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Using `[self class]` can lead to `[a isEqual:b] != [b isEqual:a]`, which I think should never be desirable (when `b` is a subclass of `a` without overriding `isEqual:`).

Comment: More specifically, if `a` is an instance of the subclass of `b`'s class, `[a isEqual:b]` will return NO (because `b` is not kind of `a`'s class) and `[b isEqual:a]` will return YES, because `a` is kind of `b`'s class. (when using `[self class]`)

Comment: No worries. I also updated my answer in regards to both `name` properties being nil.